TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getStackAddendum') in React production build
I'm encountering a TypeError when building my React application for production. The error message is:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getStackAddendum') at printWarning ... 
Context:

I'm using React 18.2.0, TypeScript 4.9.4, webpack, and craco for the build.
The application uses Module Federation to link microservices into a shell.
The error occurs in components that are part of the shell, not in imported microservices.
In development (npm start), everything works correctly. The error only appears in the production build (npm run build and npm run serve).

Code:
I have a DataTable component:
// DataTable.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Table, TableContainer, Divider } from "@mui/material";
import { DataTableBody } from "./data-table-body";
import { DataTableHeader } from "./data-table-header";
import { DataTablePaginator } from "./data-table-paginator";

export interface IDataTableProps<T> { /* ... */ }

const DataTable = <T,>(props: IDataTableProps<T>) => {
  const { columns /* other props */ } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer /* ... */>
        <Table>
          {columns.length > 0 ? (
            <DataTableHeader columns={columns} /* other props */ />
          ) : (
            <Divider />
          )}
          <DataTableBody /* ... */ />
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <DataTablePaginator /* ... */ />
    </>
  );
};

export default DataTable;


In the DataTableHeader component, I filter the columns:
// DataTableHeader.tsx
import { TableHead, TableRow } from "@mui/material";
import { DataTableHeaderCell } from "./data-table-header-cell";

export const DataTableHeader = (props: IDataTableHeaderProps) => {
  const { columns, isAdmin, isLeader /* other props */ } = props;

  const filteredColumns = columns.filter((column) => {
    const { checkAdminRole, checkLeaderRole } = column;
    if (
      (checkAdminRole && isAdmin) ||
      (checkLeaderRole && isLeader) ||
      (!checkAdminRole && !checkLeaderRole)
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {filteredColumns.map((x, index) => (
          <DataTableHeaderCell key={index} {...x} /* other props */ />
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
};


Problem:
When I run the production build, I get the following error in the browser console:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getStackAddendum')
    at printWarning (vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_lib_runtime_RefreshUtils_js-node_mod-729898.chunk.js:17355:44)
    at error (...)
    at jsxWithValidation (...)
    // rest of the stack trace


Has anyone encountered this getStackAddendum error in a React production build? Why would filtering the columns array cause this error in production but not in development?

Debugging the production build: I found that if I remove the filteredColumns logic and map over columns directly, the error goes away.
Checking for undefined values: Added console logs to ensure columns and filteredColumns are not undefined.
Comparing development and production builds: Noticed that the issue only occurs in the production build.


Somewhere in your code you are trying to access the parameter 'getStackAddendum' on an object which is undefined. I can't find any reference to getStackAddendum in your provided code examples, so it must be somewhere else. Do a search in your project for 'getStackAddendum' and ensure that the parent object is always defined before you use it.

Yes, you're right... ReactDebugCurrentFrame is undefined. Interesting that this only happens after npm run build.
